# I do replace literal \xNN with their character in Perl?

Tags: perl, character-encoding

I have a Perl script that takes text values from a MySQL table and writes it to a text file. The problem is, when I open the text file for viewing I am getting a lot of hex characters like `\x92` and `\x93` which stands for single and double quotes, I guess.

I am using `DBI->quote` function to escape the special chars before writing the values to the text file. I have tried using Encode::Encoder, but with no luck. The character set on both the tables is `latin1`.

How do I get rid of those hex characters and get the character to show in the text file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ISO Latin-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1#Codepage_layout) does not define characters in the range 0x80 to 0x9f, so displaying these bytes in hex is expected.  Most likely your data is actually encoded in [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Codepage_layout), which is the same as Latin1 except that it defines additional characters (including left/right quotes) in this range.

Answer (score 1):

\x92 and \x93 are empty characters in the `latin1` character set (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) or [here](http://www.utoronto.ca/web/HTMLdocs/NewHTML/iso_table.html)). *If* you are *certain* that you are *indeed* dealing with `latin1`, you can simply delete them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to change the character sets on the tables, or translate the non-latin-1 characters into latin-1 equivalents. I'd prefer the first solution. Get used to Unicode; you're going to have to learn it at some point. :)